# Running tests on feature branches

Tags: git, teamcity

I have a build configuration with a test VCS root that connects to git branch `dev`, 3 build steps and 1 trigger. These are my build steps:

- Build tests
- Run tests
- Build & Deploy

I would like to run all of these build steps for branch `dev` but only two of them (build and run tests) for branches matching `feature/*`. I want this to be displayed under my build configuration. So the build configuration has a default `dev` branch that runs tests and deploys, but the `feature/*` additional branches only run tests.

How can I achieve this?

If I add `/refs/heads/(feature/*)` to the branch specification (below default branch), this works perfectly, but it always deploys - which I don't want.

[image]

**Edit 1:** There seems to be a variable available named `%teamcity.build.branch%` that you can use. But how to do a conditional in the deployment step to check if the branch is the `dev` branch. I'm not sure.

**Edit 2:** There is also a variable name `%vcsroot.branch%` that is the name of the default branch in the VCS root. So we still need a condition that checks if the `%teamcity.build.branch%` variable equals `%vcsroot.branch%`, then run the deployment step.

Comment: The 4 year old feature request is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939

Comment: Exactly, that's why leaving TeamCity is on our roadmap.

Answer (score 11):

The way to achieve what you want is to split your build into 2 builds and have dependencies between them. then you can have separate triggers between the builds.

So split the builds so you have build A which contains

- Build tests
- Run tests

and build B which contains

- Build & Deploy

Give build B a snapshot dependency on build A.

Then add a trigger to build A when a VCS check-in is detected. This will ensure that the build and tests are run on any feature branch.

Also add a trigger on build B when a VCS check-in is detected, but edit the rules so that you exclude your feature branches. When a check-in on any other branch is detected build B will start, but it needs build A to finish first so it will queue that up first, and won't start if build A fails (assuming you set that in the options)

**UPDATE**
If this is too much hassle then you might be able to play a small trick but creating a build step between Run tests and Build and Deploy which calls a command line or powershell script. Call the script passing in `%teamcity.build.branch%` and then the script can check if it was called with `dev` and `Exit 0` if so and `Exit -1` if not and this step should then fail the build and prevent the deploy. This will mean that the build will seem failed but will prevent the step you want to avoid from running. It may be possible to get teamcity not to report the build as failing if this step fails, I'm not certain

You other option is that you write a script which does the build and deploy manually and then call this script passing in the `%teamcity.build.branch%` and exit early if its not `dev` and only go on to do the actual build and deploy if it is `dev`. this won't result in a failed build but means you have to write scripts to do the things TeamCity is doing for you now.

Comment: There must be another simpler way? We have 100+ build configurations (test/staging/live). This is way too much hassle.

Comment: You didn't mention any constraint about number of build configurations. I believe this is the 'correct' way, but i'll update the answer with a hack that *might* work.

Comment: ok updated the answer. i'll look to see if you can make the build seem passed even if a step fails. Which version of TC are you running?

Comment: TeamCity Enterprise 9.0 (build 32060). Thank you for the update. I exactly thought of something similar (the script approach). :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a "test" build step (e.g. powershell script) to test if your `%teamcity.build.branch%` matches your `feature/*` pattern. You only run the following steps (in this case Build & Deploy) if previous steps were successful. Obviously the "test" step should not fail the build.